# прочитать json файл в YII2

Tags: javascript, json, yii2

подскажите как в Yii2 получить в js данные из JSON файла, который находится в одной и той же папке с файлом js, делал вот так но выдает ошибку(404):

```
var jsonResponse = $.getJSON( "test.json");
    console.log(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решился, мне надо было сделать так

```
var conf = function() {
   return ('../js/conf.json');
}
```

или создать правильный URL-адрес, используя urlHelper

```
<?= 'var url_base = "' . \yii\helpers\Url::base() .'";'; ?>
var conf = function() {
   return ( url_base + '/js/conf.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Стоит попробовать эту конструкцию:

   $.getJSON("json.js", function(json){
     alert("JSON Data: " + json);
   });

и почитать: https://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/17308-poluchenie-json.html

2. Попробовать подключить json в html файле в теге script,а в js:

   var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(mydata[0].name);

Comment: извините но ваш ответ абсолютно бесполезен, решение смотрите ниже

Answer (score 0):

А может просто?

```
var conf = function() {
   return ('./conf.json');
}
```

В  смысле обращение к файлу в той же директории обычно

```
./test.json
```